# How to solve this function $f(x)$ for degree $3$ or $4$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

> If $f(x)=0$ is a polynomial whose coefficients are either $1$ or $-1$ and whose roots are all real, then the degree of $f(x)$ can be equal to$:$

> $A$. $1$

> $B$. $2$

> $C$. $3$

> $D$. $4$

My work$:$

**For linear** only four polynomials are possible which are $x+1$ and $-x+1$ and $x-1$ and $-x-1$. All of which have real roots. So the answer is $A$.

**For quadratic** we have $8$ polynomials which are $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2+x-1$ and $x^2-x+1$ and $x^2-x-1$ and $-x^2+x+1$ and $-x^2-x+1$ and $-x^2+x-1$ and $-x^2-x-1$ Here **four** of the polynomials have real roots which are $x^2+x-1$ and $-x^2-x+1$ and $-x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x-1$. So we can say that $f(x)$ can be of degree two. So $B$ is also the answer.

For cubic and quartic I don't know how to proceed. Any hints or solutions are appreciated.

Comment: How can you use the quadratic case to decide when polynomials of degree 3 and 4 have complex roots?

Comment: @Chickenmancer the thing is, after factorising a linear term from the given ($\pm1$-coefficient) cubic polynomials, the result is not necessarily in the set of quadratic polynomials considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze the cubic case.
Note that the general cubic equation
$$x^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ may be reduced to the so-called depressed cubic with the substitution $x = y-b/3$.  After the algebra, we get the equivalent equation
$$y^3+py+q = y^3+(c-\frac{b^2}{3})y+(\frac{2}{27}b^3-\frac{bc}{3}+d) = 0.$$
The discriminant $\Delta$ of the cubic is given by $p^3/27+q^2/4$.  This gives us
$$\Delta = \frac{b^3 d}{27} - \frac{b^2 c^2}{108} - \frac{b c d}{6} + \frac{c^3}{27} + \frac{d^2}{4}.$$
If $\Delta \leq 0$, the cubic has all three roots being real.
Notice that from the above equation, the smallest $\Delta$ can be is $0$ which occurs if $b^3d = -1,bcd = 1,c^3 = -1$.  This requires $c = -1$ and $b,d$ to have opposite signs.  This indeed is possible.
For example, $x^3-x^2-x+1 = 0$, has roots $\pm 1$ with $1$ being a double root.

Comment: Very nice answer. Just two things to ask. Can't we do the cubic stuff also by descartes' rule of signs and shouldn't the discriminant be $-4p^3-27q^2$$?$

Comment: You can probably also use Descarte's rule for the cubic.  I just didn't try it!  Also, please read @Oscars answer.  He seems to suggest that my use of the rule of signs might not be the most careful.  I will need some time to process what he is saying.

Comment: @Doug you seem to argue that the pattern $+-+-+$ allows only two positive roots. It actually allows as many as four. You're supposed to count sign inversions, not individual $+$ or $-$ signs.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, yes, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The cubic case is handled by noting that

$(x-1)^2(x+1)=x^3-x^2-x+1=0$

has all of its roots real.

For the quartic case, we do not have such a simply soluble case. But we can use Descartes' Rule of Signs, if we are careful with it.

For instance, when we have all coefficients positive, as in $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$, four negative roots are allowed. As we will see, that particular equation does not have such roots, but $x^4+10x^3+35x^2+50x+24=0$ with the same sign pattern does (the polynomial is $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)$). The question, then, is how to refine the Rule of Signs so as to distinguish $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$ from $x^4+10x^3+35x^2+50x+24=0$.

We can improve the bounds from the Rule of Signs by multiplying in factors that will cause the product to have zero coefficients, which is likely to cut down on the sign changes and thus lead to fewer allowed real roots. In the problem here, the coefficients of the polynomial are $\pm1$, which suggests the factor $x+1$ or $x-1$ would likely work.

Going back to $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$, then we see that choosing $x-1$ as the auxiliary factor gives

$x^5-1=0$

with sign pattern $+0000-$. This allows only one positive root, and reversing alternating signs reveals that there are no negative ones. Thus $x^5-1=0$ has only one real root, which is the root $x=1$ from the multiplier, leaving none for the original quartic equation $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$.

Now try $x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1=0$. With $x-1$ as a multiplier we get

$x^5-2x+1=0$

$+000-+$

This gives two possible positive roots and one possible (sure) negative root; discounting the introduced root $x=1$ this means $x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1=0$ could have up to two real roots.

By itself that does not mean the equation does not have all real roots; the roots could correspond to repeated factors. But if there is a root with repeated factors the Rule of Signs will actually count the root with that multiplicity. For instance, $x^3-x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x-1)^2=0$ technically has only one positive root, but the corresponding factor appears twice (squared) and the Rule of Signs will count it as two. With this qualification, the bound of two real roots for $x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1=0$ already includes whatever multiplicity of factors there may be, and we are forced to accept that this case actually does not give all real roots.

We go through all the possible cases and determine whether four real roots are possible after trying out the multiplier $x-1$ as above, and if the equation survives that test we then try it also with the auxiliary factor $x+1$ (which the four-root bound must also survive).

Did I say all the possible cases? Actually if we are smart about our trial choices, we need to test only half of them because if any function $P(x)$ fails with $x-1$ as the multiplier, $P(-x)$ will fail with $x+1$ and vice versa.

Then, if any of our eight trials results in a quartic equation that could have four real roots including appropriate multiple factor-counts, we must examine that case more precisely to see if all those real roots actually exist.

> All of the possible cases fail with the Rule of Signs augmented by a factor of $x+1$ or $x-1$. So no fourth-degree equation with all coefficients $\pm1$ can have all roots real. Further testing shows that Descartes' Rule of Signs with the auxiliary factors $x\pm1$ also rules out all possibilities fir degree 5, and it seems likely for higher degrees as well.

Answer (score 1):

The given property of the coefficients tells us that for each degree $ \ n \ , \ $ if $ \ f(x) \ $ is in the set of polynomials, so are $ \ f(-x) \  ,  \ -f(x) \  ,  $ and $ \ -f(-x) \ \ ; \ $ there are $ \ 2^{n+1} \ $ such polynomials altogether.  So the number of polynomials needing to be examined can be reduced by a factor of four; it will suffice to consider those with a leading coefficient of $ \ +1 \ \ . $

For the linear $ ( \  n \ = \ 1  \  ) \ $ polynomials, we can just look at $ \ f_1(x) \ = \ x + 1 \ \ ; \ $ as there are only four such polynomials in the set, *all* of them have only real zeroes.  The quadratic $ ( \  n \ = \ 2  \  ) \ $ polynomials with two real zeroes must have positive discriminant (or be of the form $ \ \left(x \pm \frac12 \right)^2 \ - \ \frac54 \ ) \ \ , $ so $ \ f_2(x) \ = \ x^2 \pm x - 1 \ \ $ and their vertical reflections have two real zeroes (four of the eight possible quadratic polynomials).  [You probably worked out the zeroes by arguments such as these.]

One approach for the cubic $ ( \  n \ = \ 3  \  ) \ $ polynomials is to use the Viete relations to show that for $ \ x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x + 1 \ $ with zeroes $ \ r \ , \ s \ , \ t \ \ , $ *not necessarily* distinct, we have $ \ r + s + t \ = \ \mp 1 \ \ , $ $ rst \ = \ -1 \ \ , \ \ \frac{rs \ + \ rt \ + \ st}{rst} \ = \ \frac{\pm 1}{-1} \ = \ \frac{1}{r} \ + \ \frac{1}{s} \ + \ \frac{1}{t} \  = \ \mp 1 \ \ . \ $  This tells us that the three purported real zeroes *cannot all* have the same sign.  It is not difficult to see that for  $ \ rst \ = \ -1 \ \ , \ $ these equations can be solved consistently by $ \ r \ = \ -1 \ \ , \ \ s \ = \ t \ = \ +1 \ \Rightarrow \ r + s + t \ = \ +1 \ \ , \ $ which produces $ \ f_3(x) \ = \ x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 \ = \ (x + 1)·(x - 1)^2 \ \ ; \ $ with  $ \ rst \ = \ +1 \ \ , \  \ r \ = \ +1 \ \ , \ \ s \ = \ t \ = \ -1 $ $ \Rightarrow \ r + s + t \ = \ -1 \ \rightarrow \ g_3(x) \ = \ x^3 + x^2 - x - 1 $ $ = \ (x - 1)·(x + 1)^2 \ = \ -f_3(-x) \ . \ $  The  vertical reflections of these polynomials will also have three real roots, for a total of four out of 16 possible cubic polynomials.

[I'll set out a similar discussion for the next higher degree, just to show what is involved; much more succinct arguments are provided by other posters.]

When we come to the 32 quartic $ ( \  n \ = \ 4  \  ) \ $ polynomials, using Viete relations becomes a far more daunting (and not generally enlightening) task, since for *four* real zeroes, we *could* have one single and one triple zero; two double zeroes; two single and one double zero; or four distinct zeroes.  We can deal with the first two cases as we did above:

• For zeroes $ \ r \ , \ s \ $ [multiplicity 3]  , we need to have $ \ r + 3s \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ ,  \ \ r·s^3 \ = \ -1 \ \ $ in order to obtain real solutions at all; however, the two pairs of solutions are found (with some computational aid, or a lot of patience) to be inconsistent with the other Viete equations $ \ 3rs + 3s^2 \ = \ 3s·(r + s) \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ , $ $ 3rs^2 + s^3 \ = \ s^2·(3r + s) \ = \ \pm 1 \ ; $

• For zeroes $ \ r \ , \ s \ $ [each of multiplicity 2]  , we require $ \ 2r + 2s \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ ,  \ \ r^2·s^2 \ = \ +1 \ \ , \ $ for which it is not so difficult to find real solutions $ \ r \ = \ \frac14  +  \frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} \ \ , \ \ s \ = \ \frac14  -  \frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} \ \  $ or $ \ r \ = \ -\frac14  +  \frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} \ \ , \ \ s \ = \ -\frac14  -  \frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} \ \ [rs \ = \ -1] \ \ ; \  $ but again, these solutions are not consistent with both  $ \  r^2 + 4rs + s^2  \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ $ *and* $ \ \ 2r^2s  + 2rs^2 \ = \ 2rs·(r + s) \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ . $

At this point, we find that we want some other "device" in order to complete our argument.  The second derivative $ \ f''_4(x) \ = \ 12x^2 \pm 6x \pm 2 \ $ has either

• no real zeroes for $ \ 12x^2 \pm 6x + 2 \ \ , \ $ corresponding to quartics with no points of inflection, which means there cannot be *four* real zeroes; or

• two real zeroes for $ \ 12x^2 \pm 6x - 2 \ \ , \ $ thus quartics with two points of inflection.

The candidate quartic polynomials are then $ \ x^4 \pm x^3 - x^2 \pm x \pm 1 \ \ $ with the existence of two inflection points thus excluding the third case (two single and one double zero).  So these polynomials will have to possess four *distinct* real zeroes. To winnow the candidate list further, we can consider the first derivative $ \ f'_4(x) \ = \ 4x^3 \pm 3x^2 - 2x \pm 1 \ \ , $ for which we will want *three* real zeroes.  There are just four possibilities  to check: the cubic discriminant is only positive for $ \ f'_4(x) \ = \ 4x^3 \pm 3x^2 - 2x \mp 1 \ \ , \ $ corresponding to
$$ x^4 \ + \ x^3 \ - \ x^2 \ - \ x \ \pm 1 \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ x^4 \ - \ x^3 \ - \ x^2 \ + \ x \ \pm 1 \ \ . $$
But these are horizontal reflections of one another, so it remains to discuss, say,  $  \ f_4(x) \ = \ x^4 \ + \ x^3 \ - \ x^2 \ - \ x \ \pm 1 \ \ . $

The curve for this polynomial has three "intervals of concavity", so it allows the possibility that it could have four $ \ x-$intercepts, and so four real zeroes for the polynomial.  Let us examine the behavior of $  \ p_4(x) \ = \ x^4  +  x^3  -  x^2  -  x  \ = \ x·(x + 1)^2·(x - 1) \ . $  Since $ \ \lim_{x \ \rightarrow \ \pm \infty} \ p_4(x) \ = \ +\infty \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ $ is a "touching" $ x-$intercept. this function has relative minima at $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ $ and $ \ 0 \ < \ x_{min} \ < \ +1 \ $ and a relative maximum at  $ \ -1 \ < \ x_{max} \ < \ 0 \ \ . $  Short of checking a graph or solving $ \ p'_4(x) \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ we can estimate the "size" of the turning-points in the function curve by $ \ p_4 \left(-\frac12 \right) \ = \ \frac{1}{16} - \frac18 - \frac14 + \frac12 \ = \ +\frac{3}{16} \  $ and $ \ p_4 \left(+\frac12 \right) \ = \ \frac{1}{16} + \frac18 - \frac14 - \frac12 \ = \ -\frac{9}{16} \ \ . $  (The actual values are $ \ x_{max} \ = \ \frac18 - \frac{\sqrt{17}}{8} \ \approx \ -0.390 $ $ \Rightarrow \ p_4 \left(x_{max} \right) \ \approx \ +0.202 \ \ , \ \ x_{min} \ = \ \frac18 + \frac{\sqrt{17}}{8} \ \approx \ +0.640 $ $ \Rightarrow \ p_4 \left(x_{min} \right) \ \approx \ -0.620 \ \ . $ )

What we find from this is that the "ripples" at the "bottom" of the function curve are not "large enough" to "touch" or "cross" the $ \ x-$ axis when $ \ p_4(x) \ $ is "vertically shifted" by $ \ \pm \ \ 1 . \ $  So $ \ p_4(x) + 1 \ = \ x^4  +  x^3  -  x^2  -  x + 1 \ $ has *no* real zeroes and $ \ p_4(x) - 1 \ = \ x^4  +  x^3  -  x^2  -  x - 1 \ $ has only two, one positive and one negative.

So we have "eliminated" *all* of the possible quartic polynomials of the prescribed form:  **none** of them can have four real zeroes.

[We can also apply the derivative analysis to the cubic polynomials.  We see that the first derivative only has real zeroes for $ \ f'_3(x) \ = \ 3x^2 \pm 2x \ - \ 1 \ = \ (3x \mp 1)·(x \pm \ 1) \ $ and the second derivative yields $ \ f'_3(x) \ = \ 6x \pm 2 \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ x_{infl} \ = \ \mp \frac13 \ \ . $  These two possibilities are horizontal reflections of each other, so we can focus on $ \ f_3(x) \ = \ x^3 - x^2 - x \pm 1 \ \ , $ with its maximum at $ \ x \ = \ -\frac13 \ , \ $ inflection point at $ \ x \ = \ +\frac13 \ , \ $ and its minimum at $ \ x \ = \ +1 \  \ . $  Only $ \  x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 \  $ has its minimum on the $ \ x-$axis, thereby producing a double zero there and a single zero at $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ \ . \ $  Hence, the only "unit-coefficient" cubic polynomials with three real zeroes are $ \ f_3(x) \ = \ x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 \ \ , \ $ its horizontal reflection, and their two vertical reflections, as we determined above.]

This was not intended in any way  as a brief answer; I was interested in the behavior of this class of polynomials and wanted to investigate what "lay under" the conclusions of the shorter answers.  The analysis  done here suggests that there are also **no** higher-degree polynomials of this type which have *solely* real zeroes: it does not appear to be possible to obtain "large enough" or "numerous enough" turns in their curves to produce the requisite number of $ \ x-$intercepts.   (I have tested this for $ \ n \ = \ 5 $ and $ \ 6 \ \ . \ ) $

Answer (score 0):

By the Rational Root Theorem, if such a polynomial has a rational root, it must be $x = \pm 1$.  It turns out that 8 of the 16 possible cubics (the ones with even numbers of + and - coefficients) have such a root.

For a quartic, we get $f(x) = \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x \pm 1 = \pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 1$, which always works out to an odd number, never zero.  So $f$ has no *rational* roots.  Proving that there are no *real* solutions can be done using Descartes' Rule of Signs, as in the other answers.